# Polymer, Materialize redundant scrollbar in google apps script spreadsheet addon

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, polymer, materialize

Great day to **Everyone**!

Recently I have decided to use **Polymer** in my spreadsheet application.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

Although I found this library pretty amazing, I faced with very unpleasant problem. When I launch my addon a **redundant scrollbar appears** which I can't even scroll:

http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/1191/378023/150914/e4b6421946.jpg

If I zoom out it disappears:

http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/1191/378023/150914/a76db2326a.jpg

It doesn't matter at which zoom position I launch the app, this scrollbar will always emerge and will disappear once I zoom out.

The same problem happened when I tried to use **materialize**:
http://materializecss.com/

I've never seen this problem when I used *bootstrap* in my app.

Sidebar.html:

```
<!--Polymer-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-    cdn/1.0.1/lib/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-  cdn/1.0.1/lib/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">

<div class="sidebar branding-below">
<paper-material elevation="1">
    <paper-tabs selected="0" noink>
        <paper-tab noink>
            <a href="#day" class="tab-link horizontal center-center layout">Day</a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>
            <a href="#month" class="tab-link horizontal center-center layout">Month</a>
        </paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>
            <a href="#year" class="tab-link horizontal center-center layout">Year</a>
        </paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
</paper-material>
</br>
</div>
```

Hope for your help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. Check out the issue at:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5164&q=scrollbar&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

There is a workaround posted:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5164#c17

In short add the following line to your client:

```
parent.document.getElementById('userHtmlFrame').style.overflowY = "hidden";
```